# "No handler for type [version]" when using Elastic Search 7.10.2

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, version

I upgraded my Amazon OpenSearch service to use Elastic Search 7.10 so that I can use the data field type "Version" (Documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/version.html)), however I still cannot create an index that uses the Version field type because it throws a `mapper_parsing_exception`. The error message is `No handler for type [version] declared on field [testField]`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is the curl command and response for creating a new index:

```
$ curl -X PUT ${host}/test-index -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"mappings":{"properties":{"testField":{"type":"version"}}}}'
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [version] declared on field [testField]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No handler for type [version] declared on field [testField]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [version] declared on field [testField]"}},"status":400}%
```

where `${host}` is an environment variable pointing to the elastic search server,

`test-index` is the new index name,

and `testField` is the new field name.

---

This is a prettified version of the custom configuration:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "testField": {
        "type": "version"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

This is a printout of the Elastic Search version (which is 7.10.2):

```
$ curl $host
{
  "name" : "9d6bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "cluster_name" : "5971XXXXXXXX:my-custom-environment",
  "cluster_uuid" : "RbQGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2022-02-10T09:41:23.620550Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from 7.10.0 version, ES can support version type
[Here is the datatype support in 7.10.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping-types.html)

Comment: That's why the OP says they updated to 7.10.2 in the first place, so presumably they already know that. This doesn't tell them why it isn't working for them, however.